# Is there a way I can remove the lighting when rendering animation?

Tags: rendering, animation, lighting

I want my animation when rendered to look like this for example[image]

but when the animation is rendered it looks like this[image]

Is there a way I can do this? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to make your object brighter, you can change the scene settings (lights and world color + strength):

[image]

Or you can plug your image into the *Emission* input of your *Principled BSDF* and even play a bit with the *Emission Strength*, as the object emits light its texture will much less depend on the scene settings:

[image]

You could even mix a *Diffuse* with an *Emission*, which may give you more control:

[image]

If you want to avoid any shadow and only need *Emission*, then directly plug the image into an *Emission* node:

[image]